# Shortest paths Knights Tour

Tags: code-review, algorithm

I am trying to print the minimum steps needed to traverse a chessboard as a knight from one diagonal position to the other. I have the following code:

## **Building the chessboard**

I started with creating the chessboard as a 100 x 100 arrayplot. The problem I seem to be having is merging it with the KnightsTour and travPath code. Reference for this code is linked in the last paragraph:

```
Chessboard=ArrayPlot[Table[Mod[j+i,2],{i,100},{j,100}],
ColorRules->{1->RGBColor[0,.55,.77],0->RGBColor[.67,.9,.99]},Frame->False,
DataRange->{{1,100},{1,100}}];(*Standard re-sizeable chessboard*)
```

## **Describing the Diagonal Knights Tour**

From my readings,the algorithms "Manhattan Distance" decreases for each move on the board such that (100-1)+(100-1)=198, therefore any two move advance cannot close in by anymore than 3:

```
KnightsTour[i_IntegerQ, j_IntegerQ]:=Module[{m},m = i-j;If[j>m,2.((j-m)/3)+m;m-2.((j-m)/4),(*Denote the decrease in the Manhatten Distance*)
If[i==1 & j==1,3;If[i==2 & j==2,4;]]]];
```

## **Showing the Path Traversal**

This line uses FindHamiltonianPath to follow and highlight the path of traversal according to the algorithm above. I am having trouble in this section because the graphics will not combine here, throwing the following error:

```
Could not combine the graphics object in Show [{},, HighlightGraph[KnightsTour, PathGraph[KnightsTour[[1 ;; 1]]], 
   PlotTheme -> "Marketing", GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehilightHide", 
   EdgeStyle -> Thickness[0.1]]}]
```

```
travPath = FindHamiltonianPath[KnightsTour[1,1]];
Manipulate[Show[{Chessboard,HighlightGraph[KnightsTour,PathGraph[KnightsTour[[;;i]]], (*Chessboard should play out the steps taken by the knight*)
PlotTheme->"Marketing",GraphHighlightStyle->"DehilightHide",
EdgeStyle ->Thickness[0.1]]}],{i,1,Length[travPath],100},
SaveDefinitions->True]
```

I had copied the manipulation code from [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/graphs-and-networks/the-knights-tour.html?product=language), not sure why this won't work for the chessboard that I developed, nor the checkerboard I had copied from the site hyperlinked in this text.

I would like to fix these errors here, any hints are appreciated. I would also like to improve upon the code by printing out the minimum steps taken as the knight traverses the board from the diagonal. Again, I appreciate any insight here.

Comment: `travPath = FindHamiltonianPath[KnightsTour]` "KnigtsTour" needs arguments

Comment: @DanielHuber I implemented those changes and still got the same errors. Thanks for the suggestion though, it seems like it would make sense to give it an input of i=j=1 to start at the diagonal.

Comment: `KnightsTour[i_IntegerQ, j_IntegerQ]` should read: `KnightsTour[i_?IntegerQ, j_?IntegerQ]`. Then` FindHamiltonianPath` wants a graph object as first argument, not a number.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you, I'll find an alternative solution here.